# Warnings disappear from VSCode terminal after killing terminal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, terminal, warnings

I'm fixing all warnings of a react typescript project like unnecessary imports, unused variabels, syntax warnings... . All these warnings are shown in VSCode terminal with the corresponding file linked above.
But after any terminal killing, all warning disappear from terminal and only some webpack , ENOENT and modules warnings are shown in terminal.
How can I see those warnings again?

restating VSCode and System doesnt work!

Comment: these warnings/errors are bound to a problem matcher that gets killed when the terminal terminates, run the same command/task

Comment: @rioV8 But rerunnig terminal again does not cause problrm matcher runs again!!! Even restarting system or VSCode, reopening project and clearing node module and reinstalling doesnt work. The only thing worked was recloning project from git!!!

Comment: Have you tried re-building the project? That normally executes eslint again and re-evaluates the warnings/errors.
Also, highly recommend to use [VSCode ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) which will show the same errors and warnings inline in your text editor.

Comment: @binginsin "npm run build" shows all the warnings once! After "npm start" only warnings for the opened files will be listed and killimg terminal makes no to show any warnings even fo open files!